# Como copiar dados de outro site com PHP?

Tags: php

Preciso pegar dados de outro site. Por exemplo, eu tenho um formulário em meu painel de controle da seguinte forma:

```
<input type='text' name='navio'><br />
<input type='submit' value='consultar'/>
```

Preciso de um script que quando eu digito o nome do `navio` na caixa de texto, ele faz a busca nesse site.

Como fazer para que ele pegue [nesse site](http://www.santospilots.tk) a linha que o `navio` se localiza e jogue em meu banco de dados?

Comment: O site inteiro? uma página ou páginas específicas do site? Apenas esse site específico?

Answer (score 3):

Existem duas possibilidades:

1. Ler o site e analisá-lo com Expressões Regulares
2. Analisar sintaticamente o HTML com [DOM](http://www.php.net/DOM) ou [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/SimpleXML)

A primeira opção é a mais fácil mas não a mais segura para você pois caso você não se precavenha na ha construção das Expressões Regulares, uma vírgula (literalmente) que o desenvolvedor do site alvo modifique e a sua Aplicação pode potencialmente deixar de funcionar.

Além disso, é mais lento, pois você quase que trabalha na força bruta, casando diversos padrões e manipulando estruturas de arrays, muitas vezes multidimensionais.

Para essa possibilidade [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) muitas vezes é suficiente:

```
$html = file_get_contents( 'http://www.site.com' );
```

E **$html** você informa como alvo de sucessivos [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/preg_match), [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all), [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/preg_replace)... aqueles que você achar melhor, tantas vezes quantas precisar.

A segunda possibilidade é mais complicada caso você opte pela [DOM](http://www.php.net/DOM), mas é mais segura pois você trabalha com a hierarquia do HTML, quase igual no JavaScript. Você lista nós, itera coleções de filhos e etc.

É complicado porque a [DOM](http://www.php.net/DOM) é um conjunto de classes maciço e muito detalhado.

Se o site alvo for mais simples, pode optar pela [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/SimpleXML) que é tipo a [DOM](http://www.php.net/DOM), mas muito menos poderosa e, consequentemente, muito mais simples.

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar utilizar algum WebService.

Faz uma requisição em um determinado endereço passando o nome do navio como parametro e esse endereço te retorna um JSON contendo os dados referentes a esse parametro em formato JSON.

Aqui tem um slide explicando como criar um webservice

http://pt.slideshare.net/MarcioJuniorVieira/criando-e-consumindo-webservice-rest-com-php-e-json

Não tem como fazer o que está querendo, caso o outro site seja de terceiros e o endereço que queira requisitar não seja um endereço de webservice.

Comment: Desculpa cara, mas você viajou legal nessa. A criação de um WebService é responsabilidade do desenvolvedor do site SE ele quiser oferecer uma forma limpa e concisa de outras aplicações consumirem dados específicos sem a todo o ônus de análises sintáticas ou regulares.

Comment: Atá, então pegou o que falei e escreveu bonito....

Comment: Não, apenas respondi certo. E educadamente.